# Change format of bar_label to percent

Tags: python, format, percentage

I have a problem with a displayed bar_label and I could not find an answer to my questions regarding the format. I simply want to display the bar_label as percent. Instead of 0.45 I want it to show 45%. Was able to change the y-axis format without a problem but not the bar_label one.

I have played around with the fmt part of bar_label but was not able to solve my problem.

Any help is appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

A = [0.45, 0.17, 0.47]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X=['1', '2', '3']

hbars = ax.bar(X, A, width, color = "b")
ax.bar_label(hbars)
ax.set_ylim(0,0.55)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(1.0))
```

[here is what I want and what it plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acEXH.png)

Answer (score 4):

bar_label has its own parameter "fmt" for this:

```
ax.bar_label(hbars,fmt='%.0f%%')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a list with your desired labels:

```
A_as_ticklabel = [f"{100*a}%" for a in A]
```

And then use the `labels=` keyword argument from `bar_label` to assign a label to each bar:

```
ax.bar_label(hbars, labels=A_as_ticklabel)
```

This is the output I get with these changes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This always works for whenever I want to add percentages to bars. It will also do the job for seaborn [barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) and [countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html).

```
bars = ax.containers[0]
ax.bar_label(bars, labels = [f'{x.get_height():.0%}' for x in bars])
```